# vbscript using Wscript to run a powershell script - need the return from powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wsh

We are using vbscript in a Classic ASP page and in that vbscript I am calling Powershell using Wscript.  I would like to check the return as it is meant to tell me whether the Powershell finished successfully of not.  I have a return value in the Powershell script.  I've tried both objShell.Run and objShell.Exec and neither one is allowing the Powershell return value through to my ASP page.

**My question:**  how can I get the return values from Powershell?

**VBScript follows:**

```
'call PowerShell script with filename and printername and scriptname
strScript = Application("EnvSvcsPSScript")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
dim strCommand
strCommand = "powershell.exe -file " & strScript & " " & strFileName & " " & strPrinterName
Set strPSReturn = objShell.Run(strCommand, 0, true)

response.Write("return from shell: " & strPSReturn.StdOut.ReadAll & "<br>")
response.Write("return from shell: " & strPSReturn.StdErr.ReadAll & "<br>")
```

**Powershell script:**

```
$FileName = $args[0]
$PrinterName = $args[1]
$strReturn = "0^Successful"

"Filename: " + $FileName
"Printer:  " + $PrinterName

try
{
get-content $FileName | out-printer -name $PrinterName
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
catch
{
    $strReturn = "1^Error attempting to print report."
}
finally
{

}
return $strReturn
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your PowerShell script succeeded. Check out this example.

**Powershell script:**

```
$exitcode = 0
try
{
    # Do some stuff here
}
catch
{
    # Deal with errors here
    $exitcode = 1
}
finally
{
    # Final work here
    exit $exitcode
}
```

**VB Script:**

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim ret
ret = oShell.Run("powershell.exe -ep bypass .\check.ps1", 0, true)
WScript.Echo ret
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Now if you run the VB script you'll get 0 if the PowerShell script succeeded and 1 otherwise.
However this approach won't let you get exit codes other than 0 or 1.

Comment: Tried what has been offered, however, when I try to use "WScript.Echo ret"  to display the returned value I get the following error:    microsoft vbscript runtime error '800a01a8' object required ''

Comment: @user3567046
VBScript code is so short that I have no idea what could go wrong.
My only guess is that the missing object is `oShell` and there's something in `Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")` Maybe a typo?
Please check your code carefully or supply a complete command and code listing.